# Rails Passenger Phusion: error unknown protocol level: 6 (SocketError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, passenger

I am deploying successfully a rails application on a server (apache+passenger integration) with capistrano but the app is not running. I receive the passenger error:

```
unknown protocol level: 6 (SocketError)
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:317:in `setsockopt'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:317:in `create_tcp_socket'
  /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb:112:in `initialize'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:135:in `new'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:135:in `negotiate_spawn_command'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:158:in `<module:App>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

Does anyone have an idea where I could look/what should I check to diagnose/solve this error?

Comment: Does the user that runs your app have the privileges needed to open a socket? Apparently it fails on `setsockopt()`, so to me it seems like a permission issue. It might be a restricted account in a cloud-hosted environment maybe?

Comment: I have another branch of the app which I also deploy with capistrano (same deploy script except branch, same deploy user) which works. Unfortunately the changes between the apps are too many to be compared, but I will give a try perhaps I discover something.

Comment: It's definitely a socket binding issue, maybe tries to bind to the same port as your other app.

Comment: unknow Socket::IPPROTO_TCP for 127.0.0.1, Which is your server OS?, try running Socket.getaddrinfo("localhost", nil) from your Rails server console and paste the results.

Comment: I receive among others ["AF_INET", 0, "127.0.0.1", "127.0.0.1", 2, 1, 6] which is TCP.

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to solve the problem. During deploy with capistrano I had an error in the gem whenever that the method to_str doesnt exist in class Fixnum. As a workaround I defined the class:

```
class Fixnum
  def to_str
    to_s
  end
end
```

This definition solved my whenever deploy problem, but it messes up the passenger functionality and the result can you see in the initial question.